# Is there a way to make a program that can detect if the image has been edited?

Tags: facebook, image

I recently saw a video on facebook in which they showed a program that detected if the image is edited. It was shown on a news program so there is a chance that it may be true. The guy said something about some international standard for images and stuff and the program also gave info about the device from which the image was captured. Is it possible? If yes then how reliable is this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programs add meta information to images.

Cameras for instance might add location information. Some editing programs add information that their particular program was used to edit the image.

It can also be possible to detect that certain actual image information has been edited in such a way that is consistent with certain filters, even though there is no meta information about that in the image.

So, to answer the question, yes it is possible to know an image has been edited in some circumstances. It is not 100% reliable. It is surely possible to edit an image without letting others know that is has been edited.